# Причастный оборот или пригательное с зависимыми словами?

Tags: грамматика

На другом форуме по русскому языку увидел спорный вопрос. Обсуждалось такое предложение:

> "Начертите равносторонний треугольник со стороной, равной пяти сантиметрам"

На форуме одни утверждают, что "равной пяти сантиметрам" - причастие, другие - прилагательное. Но: прилагательное должно согласоваться в роде, числе, падеже. А здесь нет согласованности.  С другой стороны, там говорилось, что оборот можно заменить на придаточное предложение: ***"которая равняется пяти сантиметрам.***". Так чем является этот оборот?

Просьба дать обоснованной ответ, желательно с ссылкой на авторитетный источник.

Comment: Уважаемый эксперт! Зачем Вы исправили заголовок моего вопроса? Суть вопроса заключалось в том, является ли оборот равная пяти сантиметрам" причастием или же это прилагательное с зависимыми словами?  А то что прилагательное должно согласоваться в роде, числе и падеже, я сам знаю!

Comment: Уважаемый эксперт! Зачем Вы не исправили ошибку в заголовке?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это прилагательное с зависимыми словами. Глагол "равнять" образуется от прилагательного "равный",  а не наоборот (равнять - это сделать равным). А от глагола образуются причастия "равняющий, равняемый", каждый вид причастия имеет свои суффиксы.

Answer (score 2):

Это качественное прилагательное, непроизводное,старославянский вариант др.-русского "ровный".(В совр. русском имеет вторичное значение"одинаковый", а первоначальное было "ровный, плоский")  От него глагол равнять-сделать равным, а уж от глагола - причастие: равняЮЩий,равняЕМый.Так что это точно прилагательное.

```
 желательно с ссылкой на авторитетный источник.
```

В любом грамматическом словаре есть. Вот морфологический разбор на 2-х сайтах:

http://vnutrislova.net/m/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9
http://www.reright.ru/analysis/1207232~%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9.html

Со стороной (какой?), равной пяти сантиметрам - согласованное определение, выраженное прилагательным с зависимыми словами.

Answer (score 0):

Равный - это прилагательное. Причастие обозначает признак предмета по действию, здесь значения действия нет. Согласование налицо: стороной равной (тв. п., ед. ч., ж. р.).

Comment: А не образовано ли оно от глагола ''равнять''?

Answer (score 0):

Это, конечно, прилагательное. А весь оборот является обособленным распространенным согласованным определением.